# Why are the anchors in my submenu returning false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing a jquery dropdown script for my navigation submenus.  I have return false on the top level anchors but the problem is that this is also applying to the anchors in the submenus.  My script also adds chevrons to the top level links that have submenus but those are also being added to the submenu links.  What am I doing wrong?  Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gLc12jy/).  Thanks for your time.

```
<div class="nav-outter">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Multimedia</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('nav > ul > li.has-submenu').each(function() {
    $(this).find('a:first-child').each(function() {
      $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>');
      $(this).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().find('ul').each(function() {
          if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            $(this).removeClass('active')
              .slideUp(300);
          } else {
            $(this).addClass('active')
              .slideDown(300);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  });
});

.nav-outter {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav > ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
  padding: 3px 15px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #2c3e50;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #FC4349;
  border-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

nav > ul > li > ul > li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FC4349;
}

nav > ul > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px 15px 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #fff;
  color: #FC4349;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find('a:first-child')` is going to include every first child which is all of the links since each one is a `first-child`

A simpler approach would be just target the children of `has-submenu` and remove one `each`

```
$('nav > ul > li.has-submenu').children('a').each(function() {

      $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>');
      $(this).on('click', function(e) {
      .....
```

Or using your code if you had used `find('a:first')` it would have worked since you would be targeting only the first `<a>` in each of those class

Comment: I think I prefer to use a:first which worked perfectly!  Mostly because it required less modification of my code... lol.